# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2' at line 1

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

$query="UPDATE weapons SET Name='".$_POST['Name']."' , WeaponCategory='".$_POST['WeaponCategory']"' WHERE ID=.$_POST['ID']";

In my code is an error. But i can't see what the problem is?

The error is : 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2' at line 1

Comment: If that is your complete sql statement, you are missing a quote at the end.

Answer (score 4):

`AND` is used to concatenate logical conditions in `WHERE` clauses, not to separate field/value pairs in `UPDATE` statements.  Use a comma instead:

```
UPDATE weapons SET Name='GOL MAGNUM', WeaponCategory='1 Assault Rifles' WHERE ID='2
```

Also, while pasting that I just noticed the error at the end:

```
ID='2
```

If `ID` is numeric, get rid of the single quote.  If it's character, close the quoted string.  Using just one quote like that is also a syntax error.